# Convert Binary data to Bitmap in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch phot with Microsoft graph API and I am able to get successful result.

API : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}/photo//$value"

code :

```
try {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val mediaType: MediaType? = "image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        val JSON: MediaType? = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        val json = ""

        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}/photo/"+"$"+"value")
            .get()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
            .addHeader(
                "Authorization",
                token
            )
            .build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                response.use {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                    for ((name, value) in response.headers) {
                        println("$name: $value")
                    }
                    Log.d("ProfilePhoto","ProfilePhoto"+response.body!!.toString())
                    Log.d("ProfilePhoto","ProfilePhoto"+response.body!!.toString().toMediaTypeOrNull())
                    response.body?.charStream()?.readText()?.let {
                    //Where it refers to Response string
                        val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(response.body!!.byteStream())
                        val image =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream)
                        Log.d(
                            "ProfilePhoto",
                            "Success response from ProfilePhoto Media   " + response.body!!.contentType()
                        )
                        Log.d(
                            "ProfilePhoto",
                            "Success response from ProfilePhoto" + it.toString()
                        )
                     }


                    } else {
                        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
                    }

                }
            }
        })

    }catch(err : Error){
        Log.d(
            "ProfilePhoto",
            "Error response from ProfilePhoto" + err
        )
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to convert response to Bitmap but it is returning null!

I am new to kotlin and all I can understand is that response is binary data and content type of responce is image/jpeg. How can I convert this to Bitmap or Image that I can show on my Imageview.

Reponse : `������JFIF����`��`��������C�  $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342����C            2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222������"��������������������������   �����������}��!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�     %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������     ���������w��!1AQaq"2B����   #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������������?���_xkA�º<�h�k��B��i$�$�?������t����(���:/�xA����ֵ�'�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@-3��������� ֢�2�����������(����_����?�?�j('��L����8����E�=���@-3��������� ֢�2�����������(����_����?�?�j('��L����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�2������t����(����[��������?�j('�o�K����8����E�=���@/��������� ֢�<�֑�Y���;m:�6(�b�T���Uό�7Zׂ��(�Y���:/�xA����ֵ�'���(�����Z֠�(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(����Yi���w   ������`�,�t�f�x�`

Comment: why you are converting the string to bitmap ?

Comment: Can you post your API response ?

Comment: I already have check Response :

Comment: @vickykumar The response I am getting is  image/jpeg content type. and it returns as binary format

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by decoding into Base64 ,you can use the java.util.Base64 library to encode and decode strings in Kotlin.
First, let’s use the encoder to encode , “Baeldung” string, please check the sample code below

```
val originalString = "Baeldung"
val encodedString: String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalString.toByteArray())
assertEquals("QmFlbGR1bmc=", encodedString)
```

Git - https://github.com/Baeldung/kotlin-tutorials/tree/master/core-kotlin-modules/core-kotlin-strings

Comment: The issue is that when I am trying to decode it It is not waiting to receive binary data it is decoding ";@9ab39b" these which my guess is empty body

Comment: Sorry , I am getting confused , are you getting null or binary value in response ?  could you please also provide the response code ?

Comment: the gibberish code is the response

Comment: Reponse : ������JFIF��������������C�  $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342����C            2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222������"��������������������������   �����������}��!1AQa"q2��#B��R��$3br�     %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������     ���������w��!1AQaq"2B����   #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������������?���_xkA�º<�h�k��B��i$�$�?������t����(���:/

Comment: could you please check - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-kotlin/issues/9 , hope this help